# Hey guys what am i doing wrong in this code . i am trying to append all the prime factors of 13195 to an empty list but its giving me an empty list

Tags: python

```
def largestprime():
    pri_fact = []
    x = 13195
    for counter in range(2,x):
        for count in range(2,counter):
            if counter%count==0:
                break
            else:
                pri_fact.append(counter)
    return pri_fact


a = largestprime()
print(a)
```

I really dont know why this is not working. please help guys

Comment: That `break` is breaking the for loop, so you're missing iterations in the inner loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner loop logic is wrong.
If count is not a divisor of counter you need to continue searching.

Here is the fixed version:

```
def largestprime():
    pri_fact = []
    x = 13195
    for counter in range(2,x):
        for count in range(2,counter):
            if counter%count==0:
                break
        else: # <-- note corrected indent!
            pri_fact.append(counter)
    return pri_fact


a = largestprime()
print(a)
```

The "else" statement should belong with the "for" not the "if":
An else statement after a loop is executed if the loop completes normally (this is not well known, I think.)
So in your case, the append should run only when the break is not triggered, and so we put it in an else clause.

Comment: I was assuming you can only use else statement relative to the if statement. thank you so much, this works. i am trying to find out the prime factors, the largest prime factor to be precise but i think i got it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't look quite right to me, so I've made an amendment to help identify where a number is a prime factor:

```
def largestprime():
  pri_fact = []
  x = 13195
  for counter in range(2, x):
    # Check to see if counter is a factor of x
    if x % counter == 0:
      factors = 0
      # See how many factors of counter there are (>0 = not prime as we skip 1)
      for primecheck in range (2, counter):
        if counter % primecheck == 0:
          # Break if there is a factor
          factors = 1
          break
      if factors == 0:
        pri_fact.append(counter)
  return pri_fact

a = largestprime()
print(a)
```

This works like so:

1. Is `counter` is a factor of `x`?
2. If it is, look for factors of `counter`.
3. If there are *any* factors then it is not prime (as we skip 1, so the second factor makes it non-prime).
4. If `counter` has no additional factors, it's added to `pri_fact` as it's a prime factor.

Output:

```
[5, 7, 13, 29]
```

**Notes**: This could be made faster by only looking up to `x / 2`, as numbers higher than that will never be a factor.  The same applies to the inner loop `counter / 2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def largestprime():
       pri_fact = []
       x = 13195
     for counter in range(2,x):
         for count in range(2,counter):
             if counter%count==0:
              break
         else:
            pri_fact.append(counter)
     return pri_fact
  a = largestprime()
  print(a)
```